# Set table cell width to be percentage of ancestor without affecting neighboring cell widths

Tags: jquery, css, width, column-width

In HTML, I have the issue explained in this example, which you can see in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qLyjj9sd/):

```
<html>
<style>
table, td {border:1pt solid; border-collapse:collapse;}
figure {margin:0pt}
</style>
<body>
<section style="border:1pt solid; width:600px;">
  <p>This &lt;section&gt; has a surrounding border, 
  and has a fixed width of 600px solely for the purpose of the demonstration. 
  In the application I cannot predict what the width of the &lt;section&gt; 
  will be.</p>

  <p>First table with no styling except border. Not what I want because the
  third column is too wide. It is supposed to only be 25% of the ambient 
  &lt;section&gt; (which will of course be a larger percentage of the table
  than 25%).</p>

  <figure>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>
            <p>Paragraph with many many many many words.</p>
          </td>
          <td>Word</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>

  <p>Second table with its third cell at 25%. Browser takes that to mean 25%
  of the table width. Not what I want because the other cells grow to be too 
  wide.</p>

  <figure>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td style="width:25%">
            <p>Paragraph with many many many many words.</p>
          </td>
          <td>Word</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>

  <p>Third table looks the way I want it to look. The 3rd column has width 25%
  of the section width. However in this example I achieved that by knowing that
  I had set the section width to 600px, and so I manually set that cell's width
  to 150px. In my application I will not be able to predict the width of the
  ambient section. I also want to achieve this result without specifying any
  widths which would require predicting or knowing how wide "Word" will be.</p>

  <figure>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td style="width:150px">
            <p>Paragraph with many many many many words.</p>
          </td>
          <td>Word</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd like the `<td>` containing the `<p>` to have (an inline specified) width that is 25% of the `<section>` width, but let the other `<td>`s keep their natural width (the minimal width to contain their contents).

If I use `width:25%` on this one `<td>`, browsers (well, Firefox 47.0 at least) seems to find a width for that cell, then makes the `<table>` four times as wide, and makes the other three cells have the same width as the paragraph cell. This makes those other three cells too wide.

Is there a CSS or script technique I can use to achieve what I want?

---

Note: I cannot predict the width of the "Word"s. This is all automatically generated content. So I cannot manually adjust any percentages to get widths just right.

Comment: Recommend clarification - in your post you indicate the 25% is the width of `<p>` and in a response to @RMo you indicate that the 25% is for the entire `<table>` in conjunction with the minimum widths of the other cells.

Comment: @RobertC It states: "I'd like the <td> containing the <p> to have (an inline specified) width that is 25% of the <section> width". I don't say the <p> should be 25% of anything.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I tried it with jQuery this time. It seems to be trouble when you set the td with a %. So I used jQuery to calculate a new width based on the width of figure (in px).

I also added a class .figure to the last table so it would only apply there. I assume you will be able to locate the specific table based on a css selector.

If you want to apply the same on several different tables, use a loop function. But for simplicity's sake I won't do that in this example. https://jsfiddle.net/qLyjj9sd/2/

**HTML**

```
<body>
<section style="border:1pt solid; width:600px;">
  <p>This &lt;section&gt; has a surrounding border, 
  and has a fixed width of 600px solely for the purpose of the demonstration. 
  In the application I cannot predict what the width of the &lt;section&gt; 
  will be.</p>

  <p>First table with no styling except border. Not what I want because the
  third column is too wide. It is supposed to only be 25% of the ambient 
  &lt;section&gt; (which will of course be a larger percentage of the table
  than 25%).</p>

  <figure>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>
            <p>Paragraph with many many many many words.</p>
          </td>
          <td>Word</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>

  <p>Second table with its third cell at 25%. Browser takes that to mean 25%
  of the table width. Not what I want because the other cells grow to be too 
  wide.</p>

  <figure>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>
            <p>Paragraph with many many many many words.</p>
          </td>
          <td>Word</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>

  <p>Third table looks the way I want it to look. The 3rd column has width 25%
  of the section width. However in this example I achieved that by knowing that
  I had set the section width to 600px, and so I manually set that cell's width
  to 150px. In my application I will not be able to predict the width of the
  ambient section. I also want to achieve this result without specifying any
  widths which would require predicting or knowing how wide "Word" will be.</p>

  <figure class="figure">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>
            <p>Paragraph with many many many many words.</p>
          </td>
          <td>Word</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>
</section>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
table, td {border:1pt solid; border-collapse:collapse;}

figure {margin:0pt}
```

**Javascript --> jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var newWidth = $(".figure").width() * 0.25;
  $(".figure td:nth(2)").width(newWidth);
});
```

Comment: +1 And thanks for this. I may accept it eventually. I'm still seeking a javascript-free css-only solution if possible. If there isn't one, this works so I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2uokvrtn/

Did you try:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<section>
  <figure>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>Word</td>
          <td>
            <p>Paragraph with many many many many words.</p>
          </td>
          <td>Word</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
td:first-child{
   width: 25%;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That makes the table 100% of its contatiner's width, and subsequently makes the other three columns too wide. I want the table to be more narrow than that. It's final width is supposed to be 25% of the container's width plus the minimal widths for the other three columns.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2uokvrtn/1/ It works as you speciefied. Try changing figure's width in the example yourself. The table just adapts to its parents width.

Comment: I specified: "I'd like the <td> containing the <p> to have (an inline specified) width that is 25% of the <section> width, but let the other <td>s keep their natural width (the minimal width to contain their contents)." This does not do that.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case just remove the table{width: 100%;} and it works. https://jsfiddle.net/2uokvrtn/2/

Comment: Thank you so much for trying. I appreciate any help here. But I added a clarifying note. Your solution would have me somehow calculate what width the figure should be. In the jsfiddle example, I can just play with it until it looks right. However in my application I will not be able to make that step. All of the content for the HTML page will be automatically generated, and there won't be a step where a human being intervenes to set the figure width to be just right. Apologies for not clearing this up in my initial post.

Comment: You don't need to specify figure width yourself. It should be fine if the generated html does that. The only reason I added this rule is to show that it works regardless of the size of figure.

Comment: It sounds as if you are saying that if I remove the CSS figure rule (as well as the 100% table width rule) then I will have what I am asking for. But it's not so. Doing that leaves me with a first column that is too wide. I will clarify my post with some screen shots.